# 'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' - I am setting the header, but I cannot find where

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting the error `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` when I try to `POST` while using my auth middleware. I have researched and have found that I am sending data to the client before I thought I was. But I cannot work out where this is happening. I think it is in the actual middleware code because when I run the code without the middleware it works perfectly.
Please forgive my poor typing. It is a work in progress. Im still working out what objects I am going to receive.

Route
`app.post("/users/post-item", authenticate, itemController.postItem);`

Auth Middleware

```
export const authenticate = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  const token: any = req.headers["token"];
  if (!token) {
    console.log("No token");
    return res.status(400).send({ message: "Token is not provided" });
  }

  try {
    const decoded: any = await jwt.verify(token, "abc123");
    const user = await db("user").where({ id: decoded.id.id });

    req.body.user = { user };
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error);
  }
  next();
};
```

Controller

```
export const postItem = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { itemName, price, description, user, location, species } = req.body;

  try {
    items
      .postItem({
        itemName: itemName,
        price: price,
        description: description,
        userId: user.user[0].id,
        location: location,
        species: species
      })
      .then((data: any) => {
        // Header is sent somewhere before here
        res.sendStatus(200);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Something went wrong: ${error}`);
  }
};
```

PostItem function

````
export const postItem = ({
  itemName,
  price,
  description,
  userId,
  location,
  species
}: {
  itemName: string;
  price: string;
  description: string;
  userId: string;
  location: string;
  species: string;
}): any => {
  return db("item_for_sale").insert({
    name: itemName,
    price,
    description,
    user_id: userId,
    location,
    species
  });
};```
````

Comment: can your try return res.sendStatus(200); in controller file then function instead of just res.sendStatus(200).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking the `next()` after the `try..catch` as well. So the `next` function is called two times.

```
  try {
    const decoded: any = await jwt.verify(token, "abc123");
    const user = await db("user").where({ id: decoded.id.id });

    req.body.user = { user };
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error);
  }
  next();//<<<<====this next
```

Comment: Duuude!!! You legend. Ive been stuck on that for weeks. I dont even know why it was there.